# Email Piping with Thunderbird

Tags: thunderbird, email

I have a PHP script (osTicket) that has the ability for parsing piped emails.

In theory it would be very simple to execute a script and post the email source code to it.

Is there a plugin available that does that? Or is there any other possible option?

Answer (score 1):

Thunderbird does not have a way to pipe in custom scripts to send out emails.

An option you should look into would be to setup a `postfix` service on the osTicket server to allow it to send out messages from localhost out.

In the documentation mentioned by osTicket ( http://osticket.com/wiki/Email_Piping ), they talk about how to set it up for cPanel. We will be doing the same thing but on postfix:

### Step 1: Find what alias mapping you are using

`sudo postconf | grep -e ^alias_maps`

**Example result from the command above:** `alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases`

### Step 2: Edit file to add a new alias

(use any editor you want with root access)

`sudo vim /path/to/alias/file`

**Example result from the command above:** `sudo vim /etc/aliases`

### Step 3: Add this line to the alias file

`support@domain.com: "|/path/to/api/pipe.php"`

**You should change:** the email address to the one you are going to us and the path to the correct path to the pipe.php file

### Step 4: Save alias file and exit

**For vim:** `:wq!`

Depending on the editor, use the command/options to save the file and exit.

### Step 5: Initialize alias database

`sudo newaliases`

This will make sure the changes you made will be used for postfix/sendmail. This will only work if you if you are editing the `/etc/aliases` file. Read the manual page for more information on how to initialize alias data for postfix `man newaliases`.

### Step 6: Test if it works

`echo "TEST Email" | mail -s "This is a test" support@domain.com`

Once its been complete, you should be able to read the mail log to make sure it used the php script when sending it: `/var/log/mail.log`

You should see a line about it being sent but being delivered to a command: `(delivered to command: /path/to/api/pipe.php)`

### Website References

Official information from osTicket about email piping

http://osticket.com/wiki/Email_Piping

Question about postfix piping

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6723596/piping-with-postfix-aliases-and-mysql

piping.html - More detailed explanation about piping for a helpdesk service called **Vision Helpdesk**

http://www.thevisionworld.com/vision-helpdesk-faqs-exim-postfix-qmail-sendmail-email